# retrieving data from an complex excel table

Tags: excel

It's me again!

I was wondering if there is any way other than VLOOKUP to retrieve data from a somehow complex data table in excel. 
My table is a leave tracker form for employees.(screenshot and a link to the file is attached).
I created another form in another sheet in the same file to retrieve the records (which i have marked in the screenshot) from the first table for each person by entering his/her ID.  I used VLOOKUP function to do this. but it didnt work(maybe because my cell reference contains formulas) . so is there any other way that I can do this? or can you help me with the VLOOKUP function not working?
here is the link to the file: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6oRHD8KdbkyRkJkd2V2clJ0LTg/view?usp=sharing

[this is my main table containing data]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpxJj.jpg)

Comment: I want to retrieve the data from the "leave Breakup" section in my main table which I marked in the screenshot

Comment: Can you copy/paste the data in the same place by value. And then use _VLOOKUP()_?  **Pay attention of** matching fields, they must have the `same format` : both Text, Both Number, etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didnt get what you mean!

Comment: What Mohamad is saying is that your VLOOKUP might not be working due to the cell formatting of the ID you are looking up and the range of values in the lookup array is different. It may be that you main table has the IDs formatted as text and on your other sheet the ID is formatted as Text. You could test to ee if this was the problem by changing one of the IDs from 1 to A and see if the VLOOKUP works

Comment: Yes @maxhob17, This is exactly what did I mean.  It sometimes happens that VLOOKUP does not match two values that look the same, because the format of the cells that contains them is different.

Comment: I checked the formatting of the both cells and they were the same type. the col_index number for my target column is 37 (which contains a function) but when I change that number to 27(which there is no function in that cells) it shows the content of the target cell in column 27!! I thinks there is a problem with cells that contains a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a solution for your problem. U can use Countif function with double Indirect nested function in Leave Summary Sheet. Paste Formula:

**=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Leave Tracker'!"&"C"&($B$3+7)):INDIRECT("'Leave Tracker'!"&"AG"&($B$3+7)),Table2[[#Headers],[S]])**

at C5 on sheet1 and replace the "C" and "AG" ranges according to the Month range (as it will be "AH" and "BL" for February respectively). Replace the [S] at the last according to the leave type as it will be [V] for the second column. If you can send me your email, i will send you the modified sheet.